# Got fired for not working enough overtime, just before the end of probation. What should I do?

Tags: company-culture, termination, germany, startup, overtime

I'm working for a startup in Germany where all the senior employees work 10-12+ hours per day. I started off like that too because it felt awkward to leave after 8/9hours but after 3 months I stopped giving a shit and just started leaving after 9, max 10 hours.

Last week my boss calls me in for our first performance review and fires me. He said that I'm at a stage in my life where I'm 'not able to dedicate' myself 'to the work' and that this 'isn't a 9-5 job.'

WTF

I was just shattered. The overtime is unpaid and no equity or shares or anything. My probation ends next month so I'm really stuck. They gave me until end of October to work at the company but that's it.

When I was stressed in the beginning of the job with all the overtime, many of the senior members said to me, 'This isn't a big corporation where you just get paid to do nothing.' or 'everybody knows that in a startup you work 60, 70 hours a week and when you get older and lazy, then you move to big corporations with 40 hour weeks.'

I'm just shattered, burnt out and stressed at the prospect of job hunting again. My degree is in engineering but I work in project management so jobs aren't that plentiful.

EDIT: There are two other junior employees who also work similar hours as me but they have different line managers who mostly work remotely so their hours are not monitored. Early on, when I shared my discomfiture with these employees about the long working hours they seemed to believe that one should be measured by productive output rather than number of hours at the desk and especially since we don't get paid overtime, there's no reason to work more hours than necessary.

BACKGROUND: When I first arrived at the company, my CEO was extremely touchy-feely, even in front of all the other employees. He used to say things like 'I think I'm falling in love with you' but that stopped quickly. What didn't stop was all the touching and stroking my back and coming extremely close to my face so much so that I could smell his breath. That stopped too but only in the last 2 months after we had a Pakistani girl recruited and he was all touchy feely with her.

But during this 'feedback' meeting, he was like 'While we are inside this building I can only talk to you as an employer. I'm happy to give you personal advice and mentor you and we can go out to dinner and talk about it, but while we're in the office, I can't say any more than I already have.'

And I was sat there thinking 'ooh and when you were brushing your hand against my bum, then you were not my employer. pff'

Comment: No equity but expected to work crazy hours, I think you've dodged a bullet there.

Comment: I agree, you dodged a bullet. Either find a place where you get equity, or where you get paid for overtime.

Comment: In addition the belief that big corporations are for "older and lazy" people points to a toxic workplace in itself.

Comment: "when you get older and lazy, then you move to big corporations with 40 hour weeks" - this is how those "senior employees" justify allowing the company to abuse them. That kind of work environment with those hours and no reward is abuse plain and simple. Well done for snapping out of the mentality which caused you to also allow the company to do this to you.

Comment: You left a very bad place. Good for you. Congratulations for not sticking up with irregular overtime and sexual harassment.

Comment: As already said in an answer this working time is illegal. Use this fact to get a good review on your job and make them a little trouble.

Comment: This appears to be a blog post, not a Workplace question. The only part of this that looks even a little bit like a question is in the title, "what should I do?", to which the obvious and only answer is "find another job" which you already know.

Comment: Startups and small companies vary a lot (much more than big companies, IME); while some expect masses of unpaid overtime, they're certainly not all like that.  (Thank goodness :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the emotionless response is trivial: start looking for another job. If you're looking for reassurances or emotional support, this unfortunately isn't really the right platform for that. I would suggest talking to a friend or therapist or finding a site that's more discussion-focused (instead of Q&A focused like this one). If you're looking for advice on how to find out specific things about a company during the interview process to avoid similar problems in future, that might be appropriate here.

Comment: "Just before the end of probation"... They just wanted your blood.

Comment: Germany has a max 10h / day work, with 48h per 6-day-week average over 6 months. Doing more work breaks the law:  https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__3.html  You may want to talk to a lawyer - but I highly doubt you got any of this in writing so its your word against theirs. Still might want to contact a lawyer. With you still in probabtion they do not need to give you a reason for the termination - and they for sure wont give you "does not work more then 10h a day".

Comment: There is also a minimum wage by law in Germany: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindestlohn#Deutschland - About start up: I saw a job advertisement: "We are a start up, therefore we cannot pay any money, but you will be part of something great which will become big!" I did not apply, and never ever read/heard/saw anything else of this "the next big thing".

Answer (score 29):

Well, lets unpack this.

In Germany, working 10-12 hours a day over a longer period of time is *illegal* as an employee. Actually, the employee will not be sentenced, it's illegal *for the company to allow this*. The only person legally allowed to do this is the owner(s) of the company, who are probably self-employed. An employee cannot legally do this and it does not matter which title they have.

Not being paid for this overtime is *illegal*. Even if there is a clause in your contract that says so, this can only be legal if you make more money then the "Beitragsbemessungsgrenze" (85200€ in 2021). If you make less (which is very likely) then not paying overtime is *illegal* and there is no contract clause that would make it legal, because you cannot give this right away for less then that sum of money.

Now, while we have strong worker protection laws and firing people is not that easy, *during probation* it actually is. During probation you can be let go with two weeks notice for any reason or no reason at all (might sound familiar to readers from the US). You still *cannot* be fired for being part of a protected class in the AGG (sex, race, religion, etc), but you could well be fired for "you don't fit here" or "I don't like you".

If you could get hold of an official account of your overtime, you could sue the company to actually pay you for it. Normally, people do that *after* they got their last paycheck, to make sure the company is not keeping any leverage. However, the company would be stupid to keep records of their criminal behaviour, so I think they wold rather admit to the smaller offence of not having kept correct records, than actually showing how much unpaid overtime they extorted from their employees.

As a summary: your firing was legal, because you were still in your probation period, where little to no worker protection laws exist. A simple "Employee did not fit the company culture" or just no reason at all would be fine. Even if they are criminal assholes, I cannot see they discriminated against you based on a protected class. You probably cannot sue them because you don't have any record of the overtime you did.

The next step is to look forward and find a new, better job. Don't work for self-proclaimed "start ups". Nobody will call themselves a "startup" except to milk their employees for unpaid overtime and seriously crappy working conditions. Find a solid job for a solid company. Ask about regular working times in the interviews you don't get surprised again.

Comment: If they used a version control system, that should be able to prove that they worked overtime. Is there a government agency she can file an anonymous complaint with? Or file a complaint after she found a job somewhere else?

Comment: The version control system would not prove anything. Most developers have flex time, so even if she checked in things at 8 in the morning and 20:00 in the evening, the company could just claim she took very long lunch breaks. An anonymous complaint is possible, but unlikely to succeed. Courts *have* accepted employees claims of overtime over "sorry, we have no records" claims from companies, when the employee actually had a meticulous hand written log of their own starting and working times. But I guess that is not the case here, who keeps such a log just in case.

Comment: Nvoigt, they can, but then an employee would actually have to lie in court which is a huge personal risk. Actually, you could ask any of the senior employees you worked with, and they would definitely not take any personal risks by lying in court.

Comment: @gnasher729 Not neccessarily. All they'd have to say is "we didn't check, we have Vertrauensarbeitszeit". Although I'd be happy to see some court decision to the contrary.

Comment: In addition, sexual harassment is illegal too.

Answer (score 21):

You've been released. You start looking for your next job. This time, ask more questions in the interview process. Ask about their work/life balance. Ask about the culture. Ask about the things that add stress to the team. Make sure that the next company is the company that you want to work for and that it's work you want to do.

Alternately, assess your reactions and behaviors at this last job. Your peers warned you during your first few months. What did you do about it? How did you react? What should you have done then to avoid or prepare for the circumstance you're in now? Answer those questions for yourself, and bring them into the interviews prepared to address them.

Comment: Along with the introspections called for in paragraph two, I might also add that this is an opportunity to learn more about what *you* want in a job in addition to reflecting on what you did in the job. Do you want a 9-5? Do you want equity, even if it means working more? Learning these things about yourself is going to help you find a better fit next time!

Answer (score 13):

I assume you also earn below average, but "you'll learn much more than in big corporations". Been there, done that.

Even for those companies your working hours are not normal, in your case it's even illegal and your manager could go to prison for it. I suggest you create a paper trail and report them to the authorities. Such people will talk bad about you anyway and in Germany you don't need reference letters.

If you're willing to put in extra hours, I'd suggest to apply at a big consulting company, because you will get good compensation in return.

Comment: Paragraph 2 is most useful.

Comment: You're right. What I've been told is things along the lines of 'you have the opportunity to learn to do so many different things that you wouldn't normally learn in a big company.'